# Splitting text with very specific whitespace into rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large list of products that I need to import in a clients site. The data I was given is structured terribly though. To be specific, the product categories are spaced apart using white-space. Its very readable for humans, but terrible for an import file.

This is what I'm currently working with. 
[image: This]

And this is what is what I need:

[image: this]

Is there any soft of function or process I could use to achieve this goal? I cant process each of these rows by hand. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the separators really white spaces or linefeeds? Looks like the latter to me. Try copying the data in Word, then pasting back in Excel.

Comment: What do you get if you export to a CSV? It's often easier to process and restructure CSVs.

Comment: Yep, without knowing what the underlying data looks like the only suggestions I can think of are powerQuery or VBA

Comment: You can throw the kitchen sink at it.  Almost literally.  Nesting substitute, replace, clean, etc.  It gets exhaustive bit it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

*This fixes the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Helper value in `A201:A206`.
- Enter Product Name in `B201:B206`.
- Formula in cell `C201`, fill Right then Down.

  ```
   =IF($B201="Product 1",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C$196,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",LEN(C$196))), ($A201-1)*LEN(C$196)+1, LEN(C$196))),IF($B201="Product 2",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C$197,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",LEN(C$197))), ($A201-1)*LEN(C$197)+1, LEN(C$197))),""))
  ```

  **N.B.**
- Helper Value `1,2 & 3` represents Value in Row `1`, `2` & in `Row 3` in `C196:E197`
- Add more Helper value if data added to respected Cells.

*Adjust **H**elper value & **C**ell references in the formula as needed for **n**ext set of data.*